# Cython: does the __getattr__ method have to be manually implemented when creating an extension type?

Tags: python, cython

Let's say I am creating a new extension type:

```
cdef class foo:
    int x

    def __cinit__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

Do I manually have to create a `__getattr__` [special method](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/extension_types.html#special-methods)? It seems that way, because `foo.__getattr__('x')` gives me an error like so:

`ImportError: Building module simple_exttype failed: ["AttributeError: type object 'simple_exttypeexttype.foo' has no attribute '__getattr__'\n"]`

Note that I tried out the following within C-space, that is I ran the following *.pyx file:

```
cdef class foo:
    int x

    def __cinit__(self, x):
        self.x = x

myclass = foo(10)
print "myclass.__getattr__('x'): {}".format(myclass.__getattr__('x'))
```

If it has to be manually implemented, how should it be implemented, if I don't want to use Python dictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html is pretty clear about this (at the very end of the page):

- Attributes are by default only accessible from Cython (typed access)
- Properties can be declared to expose dynamic attributes to
  Python-space

So here's a workable approach (assuming you want to expose `x` as read-only and also fixing a typo in your code) -- call this w.g `cyt.pyx`:

```
cdef class foo:
    cdef int _x

    def __cinit__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    property x:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._x
```

Now, once built and installed:

```
>>> import cyt
>>> a = cyt.foo(23)
>>> a.x
23
>>> getattr(a, 'x')
23
```

I'm showing that built-in Python function `getattr` also works -- there's never any reason to get attributes other than by it or plain `a.x` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alex, but there is a usecase I have where I sometimes need to change the value of a particular variable, but I only know what the variable is by its string name -- I require this within C-space, not Python-space. How can I expose a variable to access by string name, within C-space (so, `a.x` is not an option)? Since this is all within C-space, I shouldn't have to resort to Python-space `getattr`.

Comment: @user89, you can always add to the `cdef class` a `cdef` method that performs whatever setting and/or getting you require.  Of course you'll have to add your own name-to-attribute lookup (if the variable's name is known at compile time, it's simplest to have multiple methods `cdef set_x`, `cdef get_x`, etc; if not, you're trying to re-implement yourself one of the most typical functionalities of a dynamic language in a static one, which makes little sense -- but if the attributes are very few you can get away with an if/else tree of comparisons, I guess).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I understand now. I will try to think of a different way to do this.